# recvfrom() returns error 10022 when passing socket handle to thread

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsock, createthread

I'm working on UDP chat for programming classes. For now, I'm dealing with parallel in/out.

So, I'm creating thread to receive messages from server:

```
// in-thread
DWORD WINAPI in_thread(void* param)
{
    int n; // variable receivefrom returned
    char buff2[1000];

    sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);

    SOCKET my_sock;
    my_sock = (SOCKET)param; // casting from void* to SOCKET

    // reading server message

    while (1)
    {
        n = recvfrom(my_sock, buff2, sizeof(buff2) - 1, 0, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_size);
        // ......................
    }

    ExitThread(0);
}
```

And socket handle goes from:

```
hThread = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &in_thread, (void*)sock, NULL, &ThreadId);
```

But I am recieving:

> Error 10022: Invalid argument. (Returned by `rercvfrom`)

Where could it have gone wrong?

edit:

If it goes without passing to CreateThread, it works fine.
For example:

```
SOCKET sock; 
// Opening socket 
sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); 
int n; // variable receivefrom returned 
char buff2[1000]; 
sockaddr_in client_addr; 
int client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr); 
n= recvfrom(sock,buff2,sizeof(buff2)-1,0, (sockaddr *) &client_addr, &client_addr_size);
```

It works fine, socket works, no errors given, but when I pass it to createthread like in code in the question, error occures.

Using VS10, winsock2 lib.

Answer (score 0):

'my_sock', and therefore 'param' and 'sock', is not a valid socket handle. Something wrong with your socket creation code.

Comment: If it goes without passing to CreateThread, it works fine, socket works, no errors given, but when I pass it to createthread function like in code in the question, error occures. Thank you for assistance.